# React useEffect renders twice

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I know that React will render twice when using a hook like this one:

```
const [userPermissions, setUserPermissions] = useState();

//Use GET from myService to save to state
useEffect(() => {
  myService.canUserAccess(userId)
  .then(({userPermissions}) => setUserPermissions(userPermissions));
});
```

This is a huge problem given my application's logic because i need to check for the user permissions and redirect the user if the permissions are not right:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(userPermissions); //This is the output
  if(!userPermissions){ redirect(...)}
},[userPermissions, redirect]);
```

I have been debugging this and it seems that there is a first 'render': that outputs this:

```
undefined
```

And right after:

```
{ userPermissions: {...} }
```

Following my application's logic, when the state of userPermissions is first set to undefined, it will be redirected. I need to fetch this userPermissions object but the 'double render' of React is preventing me to execute the logic as desired.

Is there a way to 'load' the userPermissions object and setting it to the useState hook without triggering the 'double render' ?

Comment: From where are you providing this userId to this component? You can obviously move this API call to the parent component and supply the permissions object directly to this component. Also, you can move the redirect part inside the `then` or `catch` of your API promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it seems most reasonable to just merge it into one `useEffect`, but this may not make sense in full context of your code.

```js
const [userPermissions, setUserPermissions] = useState();

//Use GET from myService to save to state
useEffect(() => {
  myService.canUserAccess(userId)
  .then(({userPermissions}) => {
    if(!userPermissions){ redirect(...)}
    setUserPermissions(userPermissions)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you store another piece of state to know if it's loaded or not?

```
const [gettingUserPermissions, setGettingUserPermissions] = useState(true)

useEffect(() => {
  if(gettingUserPermissions){
    return; // wait until fully loaded
  }
  console.log(userPermissions); //This is the output
  if(!userPermissions){ redirect(...)}
},[gettingUserPermissions, userPermissions, redirect]);
```

Not sure how you're calling the initial loading of getting user permissions but I'm sure this can be adapted.

Comment: Technically, it works, but since it skips the first check to redirect, there is a small window where other API calls are executed. This is a leak in security, so I cannot protect the component using this.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement an extra state to check whether the promise of the asynchronous function (myService) has been resolved or not. This will skip the unwanted `undefined` results of `userPermissions` state.

```
const [userPermissions, setUserPermissions] = useState();
const [resolved, isResolved] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const userPermissions = await myService.canUserAccess(userId);
    setUserPermissions({ userPermissions });
    isResolved(true);
  })();
}, [myService]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (resolved) {
    if (!userPermissions) {
      redirect(...)
    }
  }
}, [resolved, userPermissions, redirect]);
```